# How to save selected option after page reload

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a webform with a select input and other asp, html elements, what I do is fill all the inputs and then submit my form, after submit my page is reloaded and my inputs are cleaned, so what I want to do is do exactly the same but keeping the option selected (only when user stay in that page), the page is in C#.

- I can't use localStore because I want to keep the option selected only when user stays in that page.
- The only code for clean an input is the following.

  `this.Idtxt.Text = "";`

What can I do? Exists an option to do this or should I prevent page reload.

PD. I'm using C# ASP.NET WebForm, jQuery, JavaScript.

Comment: are you familiar with Session variables or ViewState....?

Comment: Yes, with ViewState more or less

Comment: try with a Session variable and utilize some IsPostBack checks in your page load else ..... this not that difficult

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your problem, ViewState should be handling this unless something in your code is preventing it. Are you cleaning your inputs for all page loads, or are you checking for post back first? Can you post a simplified version of your code please?